# Appending series to list, then converting to dataframe. Everything works, but if list gets too large it returns a numpy memory error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, memory, append

The code works fine and outputs exactly what I need, but when db_diff_3 gets above about 5k lines, it spits out a memory error and breaks. It is using a lot of memory here (almost 7gbs) when running. A 5K list should be small for a list of series which is why I'm not understanding why its doing this. Any help would be appreciated. Sample of db_diff_full_2 below code.

````
db_diff_3 = []
db_diff_drops = []
db_diff_adds = []
    for r, c in db_diff_full_2.iterrows():
        for i in db_diff_full_2.columns.get_level_values(0):
            if db_diff_full_2.loc[r, (i, 'Old')] != db_diff_full_2.loc[r, (i, 'New')]: #compare old vs new values for each column (i) in each row. if at least one col has a difference, append entire row.
                try:
                    if len(db_diff_full_2.loc[r, ('CompanyName', 'New')]) < 1:
                        #db_diff_drops.append(db_diff_full_2.loc[r])   # add new add records to separate frame. can shut this line off to aid in memory useage
                        db_diff_full_2.drop(index=[r], inplace=True)  #drop new add records from file
                        #print('Dropped', r)
                        break
                    elif len(db_diff_full_2.loc[r, ('CompanyName', 'Old')]) < 1:
                        #db_diff_adds.append(db_diff_full_2.loc[r])    # add deleted records to separate frame - these likely were dissolved. can shut this line off to aid in memory useage
                        db_diff_full_2.drop(index=[r], inplace=True)  #drop deleted records from main list
                        #print('Added', r)
                        break
                    else:
                        db_diff_3.append(db_diff_full_2.loc[r])  # add any records with changes in old vs new columns values to changes file
                        break
                except np.core._exceptions.MemoryError:  #exception if export file is too large
                    print("File too large to export!!")
                    return  #end script if cannot add any more lines to main db_diff_3```

```                                CompanyName                                ... IncorporationDate
                                        Old                           New  ...               Old         New
CompanyNumber                                                              ...
08209948                              ! LTD                         ! LTD  ...        11/09/2012  11/09/2012
11399177                             !? LTD                        !? LTD  ...        05/06/2018  05/06/2018
11743365       !BIG IMPACT GRAPHICS LIMITED  !BIG IMPACT GRAPHICS LIMITED  ...        28/12/2018  28/12/2018
13404790                       !GOBERUB LTD                  !GOBERUB LTD  ...        17/05/2021  17/05/2021
13522064                      !NFOGENIE LTD                 !NFOGENIE LTD  ...        21/07/2021  21/07/2021```
````

Comment: Can you describe what task your code is accomplishing? Can you provide example data for `db_diff_full_2` and what `db_diff_d` should look like?

Comment: The code is outputting changes from db_diff_full_2, which is a multiindex that contains a unique number for each record in the index (CompanyNumber), then an "old" and new" level 1 column for each level 0 column. Where there is a difference in old vs new for any column, the script appends the entire row record to a list (db_diff_3) that is later converted into a new df. 

The end goal is to identify all of the rows in the multiindex where there is at least one difference between the old and new columns values. 

The below lists can be ignored
db_diff_drops = []
db_diff_adds = []

Comment: Thanks for explaining! I'm not sure why there are memory errors. One red flag, which may or may not be related to your memory issue is that you're editing `db_diff_full_2` with `drop` while iterating through it with `db_diff_full_2.iterrows()`

Comment: Actually I think the memory isssue might be because your double `for` loop would add the same row to `df3` multiple times if multiple columns had mismatches?

Comment: @mitoRibo - I believe the break in the for loop should kick it out of the loop through columns after the first mismatch. Also in the output df there are not multiple rows for the same index.

Comment: you're definitely right, I wonder what the issue was then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why your code gives a memory error but I wanted to share an approach that doesn't require the `for` loop and I believe shouldn't cause a memory issue.

The main idea is to separate the `old` and `new` parts of your `df2` table into separate tables to make comparing easier. I've created an example test table and the variable `df2` refers to your `db_diff_full_2`

```
import pandas as pd

#Create an example table
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    ('Company_name','Old'):['A','B','C','D','E'],
    ('Company_name','New'):['A','','C','D','E'],
    ('IncorporationDate','Old'):['Jan 1','Jan 2','Jan 3','Jan 4','Jan 5'],
    ('IncorporationDate','New'):['Jan 8','Jan 2','Jan 3','Jan 4','Jan 5'],

})

df2.index.name = 'CompanyNumber'

print(df2)

#Separate old and new columns into separate tables
old = df2.loc[:,pd.IndexSlice[:,'Old']]
new = df2.loc[:,pd.IndexSlice[:,'New']]

#Drop the multi-column index on old/new
old.columns = old.columns.droplevel(1)
new.columns = new.columns.droplevel(1)

#Test whether each row has ANY mismatches between old and new in any column
any_column_mismatch = old.ne(new).any(axis=1)

#Test if the old or new name is blank (in which case we don't want it to go to df3)
old_name_not_blank = old['Company_name'].apply(len).gt(0)
new_name_not_blank = new['Company_name'].apply(len).gt(0)

df3 = df2.loc[any_column_mismatch & old_name_not_blank & new_name_not_blank].copy()

print(df3)
```

Here's what `df2` looks like:

[image]

Only the CompanyNumber 0 row is copied to `df3`. The CompanyNumber 1 is not copied over because the `New` name is blank

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew there had to be a more efficient way in doing so. This works